# objective - C: Adding to a Previous NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Here I have some code that gets an `NSString` (`passedValue1`) by using a delegate. Once I have the value I displayed and saved the value into a label. However, once I have another value from `passedValue1`, I would like to add the new value I have to the previously saved value.

Can anyone help??

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    if(passedValue1){
        label.text = passedValue1;

        NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defults setObject:label.text forKey:@"labelkey"];
        [defults synchronize];
    }
    label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"labelkey"];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "add", do you mean you want a list of saved values or do you want to append the new string to the end of the old string?

Comment: your question is not elaborating what exactly you want to do. please make your question clear enough so people can understand you question and answer it.

Comment: @maddy append is the process i mean

Comment: NSUserDefault stores value with unique key only, if you provide same key then previous value will be overwritten by new one. i hope this is what you want to ask

Comment: @Dipen Panchasara I am new to objective - C so how would i come about doing this

Comment: its alright, but its basic about keyvalue coding, read documents available by Apple. your problem solved or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It turns out that in fact, the old and new values should be numbers and the values should be added together. Here is an updated answer:

If you want to add the new value to the old value then something like this should do what you want (this assumes `passedValue1` is an `int`):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    static NSString *key = @"labelKey";

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (passedValue1) {
        int oldValue = [defaults integerForKey:key];
        int newValue = oldValue + passedValue1;

        [defaults setInteger:newValue forKey:key];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [defaults objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you but instead of display both values i just want to display them as one added together

Comment: When I asked, you said you wanted the values appended. Are the values actually numbers that you want added together? If they are numbers, why do you use `NSString` instead of `int` or some other numeric data type?

Comment: The value is a NSString

Comment: Then what do you mean by "added together"? Please give an example of an old value, a new value, and the result you want.

Comment: I am making a game which send a score through a delegate in a NSString format to my homepage . So for example i play my level and score a value of 10. The value is then sent through a delegate and displayed in a label where it is then saved. Then lets say i replay the level and i score 10 again so then i would like to take the previous saved value and add it to the new value that i have just received from the level. Once that is done i would like to save the new value of the both added in this case 20

Comment: Then why are you using an `NSString`? If you are dealing with numbers then use an appropriate data type such as `int`. I'll update my answer with the assumption that `passedValue1` is an `int`.

Comment: I have to use a NSString so is there a way of converting from NSString into a int or not???

Comment: You don't have to use a string. Strings are for text. Integer types are for (integer) numbers. If you are keeping track of the score in a string then you are doing it wrong. You only convert the number to a string when you want to display the number - like I did in my answer.

Comment: but I'm getting the value of my passedValue1 from a label therefore it has to be a string

Comment: Then, as I said, you are doing it wrong. You don't store data in a label. Keep an `int` variable around for the actual number. Only use the label to display the value.

Comment: I have used 
        score++;
    scorelable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];
and then        secondviewData.passedValue = scorelable.text;